# Passing custom values to form fields

Tags: django, django-forms

I have a Post form, and i want to render some custom values at template layer. My Post form is something like this:

```
class PageForm(forms.ModelForm):
    language = ...
    translation_of = ...

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(PageForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['language'].wrapper_attrs = {'class': 'left'}
        self.fields['translation_of'].wrapper_attrs = {'class': 'right'}
```

My template is like this:

```
{% for field in form %}
    >> {{ field.wrapper_attrs }}
{% endfor %}
```

When i render that template, expecting to see a dict object or something like this. But getting nothing. Have any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

After the form's instantiation, its `__getitem__()` and `__iter__()` return a `BoundField` instead of the original `Field` instance. The `BoundField` is `"A Field plus data"` for rendering, thus you could try `{{ field.field.wrapper_attrs }}`